# htaccess rewrite doesn't work after installing WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've recently installed WordPress. Since I want it running from the root directory and like some nice looking permalinks i've added a new section to my htaccess file on the httpdocs of my server.

Since this time the redirect for other domains isn't working anymore.

This is the current code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect to other DOMAINS
#----------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example1.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/e1/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /e1/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example2.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/SR/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /SR/$1

#ALTERNATE DOMAINS
# ---------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gw.nl$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gw.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gw.info/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.cb.nl$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cb.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gw.info/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The WordPress site works as it should. Alternate domains works as well. However, the other two sites are totally out of the running, now displaying the main wordpress website.

If I change `RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` it will return an internal server error.

Anybody got a clue what's the mistake?

Comment: Maybe the flags (`[R=301,L]`) are missing in the first 2 rules and try using absolute URLs instead i.e."http://example1.com/..."

Comment: thanks Felipe! adding the flags helped !

Answer (score 0):

adding the flags

> [R=301,L]

to the first two rules worked!